# Collectives Articles endpoint broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, api

I would like to access a list of all Collective Articles on SO. I tried

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/articles?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow
```

which is the sample from [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/articles#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true). However, that failed to provide anything.

The docs page also says Invalid JSON returned. This endpoint may be broken.

Can this be updated so I can successfully get all the Collectives Articles? Although the core functionality here is broken, I’d also like to get all articles after a certain DateTime, but I imagine that’ll work once this is fixed

Comment: I get a 404 for `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/articles?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow` (and I'm now throttled by SE probably because I made their server go *pug*)

Comment: Not sure when it broke but it "worked" when the API was released: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366981/158100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint was for Stack Overflow for Teams and the Articles feature within that product. It returned Collectives Articles as an unintended side effect. When Teams moved over to a separate API, this functionality was removed from the public API.